# DataFrames. ¿Cómo organizar los valores en las columnas y modificar otros aspectos?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, dataframe

Continúo aprendiendo Python, ahora me he encontrado con la siguiente duda:

dado el siguiente diccionario:

```py
import pandas as pd

P1 = {'': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
 'Chile': [3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 7],
 'Brasil': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 'Panamá': [3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 3],
 'Uruguay': [3, 0, 2, 1, 6, 9, 1]}

print(pd.DataFrame(P1))

           Chile  Brasil  Panamá  Uruguay
0      JJ      3       3       3        3
1       G      2       1       3        0
2       P      1       2       0        3
3       E      0       0       0        0
4      GF      9       7       9        4
5      GC      7       9       3       10
6  Puntos      6       3       9        0

print(pd.DataFrame(P1).T)

          0  1  2  3   4   5       6
         JJ  G  P  E  GF  GC  Puntos
Chile     3  2  1  0   9   7       6
Brasil    3  1  2  0   7   9       3
Panamá    3  3  0  0   9   3       9
Uruguay   3  0  3  0   4  10       0
```

me gustaria preguntarles varias cosas:

1ero: Me gustaría ordenar de mayor a menor la columna 'Puntos', pero además ordenar de menor a mayor la columna 'GC', y a su vez ordenar de mayor a menor la columna 'GF'; en la medida de lo posible. Ya yo logro ordenar la columna cualquiera pero todas con valores ascendentes o todas con valores descendentes.

2do: Cuando impriman el resultado observarán que se muestra un DataFrame y que encima de 'JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos' se nos muestran unos valores, en este caso: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6...desearía poderlos no mostrar.

3ero: Me gustaría saber si es posible obtener valores del DataFrame parecido a las coordenadas (X,Y). Por ejemplo, yo se recorrer el diccionario que se utiliza para hacer del DataFrame y puedo hacer otros diccionarios eligiendo los valores que me hagan falta, pero no se hacerlo en el DataFrame, digamos, cuando lo leo desde un CSV.

4to: Lo anterior me lleva a esta pregunta: Dado un DataFrame como convertirlo en un diccionario.

5to: Y a esta otra:Dado un DataFrame como obtener varios diccionarios del mismo

Como siempre gracias por el tiempo que dedican a ayudarnos. 
Tengan por seguro que estoy aprendiendo mucho gracias a su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas. Debajo te quedo la respuesta (o la guía) a tus preguntas. Te recomiendo que veas tutoriales sobre Pandas y Python para que puedas aprender, hay varios en Youtube de buena calidad, también hay Moocs (cursos gratuitos de bastante calidad) e incluso si te lo puedes permitir, hay cursos online muy baratos (10€) que te pueden ser de gran ayuda. Espero que mi respuesta te haya servido

Answer (score 2):

En ocasiones es mejor que te enseñen a pescar, en vez de darte el pez :) . Por ello te voy a dar las respuestas a algunas preguntas, y en otras te voy a guiar para que puedas obtener la respuesta.

## 1. Ordenar puntos

En este caso te dejo la documentación de Pandas sobre `sort_values(by=[])` [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) Esa es la página de pandas y podrás ver toda la documentación. Es una documentación muy completa y llena de ejemplos, de las mejores que hay. Aquí siempre que quieras hacer algo puedes buscar las funciones que te lo hacen y ver con ejemplos como se realiza.

Te quedo el ejemplo final.

```
P1 = {'index': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
 'Chile': [3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 7],
 'Brasil': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 'Panamá': [3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 3],
 'Uruguay': [3, 0, 2, 1, 6, 9, 1]}

P1.sort_values(by=['Chile', 'Brasil', 'Uruguay'], ascending=[True, False, True])
```

## 2 Columnas número

Aquí lo que te ocurre es que cuando lees el Dataframe, no le marcas un indice, por lo que pandas, te crea un indice automáticamente (del 0 al 6), y después cuando **transpones la matriz** tu indice se convierte en las columnas.

```
#Le asigno un nombre a la columna primera, nunca se deben dejar columnas sin nombre.
P1 = {'index': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
 'Chile': [3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 7],
 'Brasil': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 'Panamá': [3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 3],
 'Uruguay': [3, 0, 2, 1, 6, 9, 1]}
```

Una vez tienes el Dataframe bien creado con todas las columnas con nombre. Te vuelvo a remitir a la documentación de Pandas para que veas `set_index()`. Para ello puedes usar el enlace anterior que te dí y navegar hasta `set_index()` o puedes realizar una búsqueda en google como "Pandas documentation set_index". La solución completa sería así.

```
#Le asigno un nombre a la columna primera, nunca se deben dejar columnas sin nombre.
P1 = {'index': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
 'Chile': [3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 7],
 'Brasil': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 'Panamá': [3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 3],
 'Uruguay': [3, 0, 2, 1, 6, 9, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(P1)
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df.T
```

## 3 Obtener datos concretos del Dataframe

Esto es una técnica concreta llamada **slicing** y es todo un mundo en la programación, es muy útil. Con ella no solo podrás seleccionar valores en Pandas, si no en tuplas, listas, vectores, etc. La documentación es extensa y puedes verla [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). Te dejo algunos métodos:

```
#Selecciono una columna
P1 = {'index': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
 'Chile': [3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 7],
 'Brasil': [3, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 'Panamá': [3, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 3],
 'Uruguay': [3, 0, 2, 1, 6, 9, 1]}
df_paises = pd.DataFrame(P1)
df_paises.set_index('index', inplace=True)

#Selecciono la columna Chile
df_pais['Chile']

#Selecciono la columna Chile y su valor primero
df_pais['Chile'][0]

#Seleccioneo la columna Chile y su valor último
df_pais['Chile'][-1]

#Seleccioneo la columna Chile y los valores segundo a cuarto
df_pais['Brasil'][1:4]

#Selecciono solo la fila JJ que es la primera
df_pais.iloc[0]
```

Como puedes ver, para Python el primer número siempre es el 0. Hay decenas de slicing diferentes, además de las que te he puesto. Si aprendes varias te ahorraran en el futuro un tiempo muy valioso.

## 4 Convertir Dataframe en diccionario

En este caso te recomiendo que busques el atributo `.to_dict()` en la documentación de Pandas o en Google (que te llevará a la documentación de pandas).

## 5 Obtener varios diccionarios de un Dataframe

Esta pregunta es muy general, y puede hacerse de distintas formas. Si quieres sacar solo una columna a diccionario o distintos números, puedes combinar el **slicing del punto 3** con el atributo `to_dict()` **del punto 4**

Comment: Muy bien todo lo que planteas. Seguiré las recomendaciones, sin embargo, en el sort_values(by=[]) no dice nada sobre poder ordenar columnas de manera diferente (ascending descending, por eso preguntaba), sino que las ordena o todas ascending o todas descending, por lo que esa pregunta todavia queda abierta jejeje. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por la paciencia de explicar todo metodicamente y pedagogicamente, gracias.

Comment: Haciendo una relectura de todo lo anterior. y llevandola a la practica, no logro eliminar el 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 con los metodos que muestras...a lo mejor es el idle que utilizo. Spyder y el phyton 3.7

Comment: Buenas @MaykelContrerasCamacho te he dejado la solución de ordenar las columnas! 
El IDLE no influye.  Lo que te sucede es: Tienes una columna que no le estás poniendo ningún nombre, en este caso la que contiene ```['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos']``` y por otro lado, Pandas siempre crea un indice por defecto, que es el número de cada fila. Cuando transpones la tabla, el indice, pasa a ser tus columnas, porque ese indice ha sido creado automáticamente por Pandas. En la documentación de set_index, indica como fijar un indice. Pero ya te he dejado el ejemplo completo de como sería :)

Comment: Falta ordenar las columnas con valores ascending y descending y ascending nuevamente.

Comment: No, no falta, por favor tomate el tiempo necesario para leerte la pregunta nuevamente hasta que lo encuentres, y lo entiendas correctamente. En concreto está en el punto uno, la documentación de pandas que te guía a como realizarlo, y después el ejemplo que te he dejado escrito, donde aparece como ordenar dichas columnas.

Comment: Rubiales gracias por tu tiempo. Lo que deseo es que se ordenen las columnas no sólo ascending, o no sólo descending, sino que sigan este orden : descending(la primera columna), ascending(la columna que viene a continuacion), descending(la tercera columna que sigue a continuacion). Espero haber explicado mi duda correctamente, sino, seguimos conversando..saludos

Comment: Sí @MaykelContrerasCamacho si eso es lo que tienes, dime si no te están funcionando por lo que sea, pero a mí me funciona, te lo escribo aquí de nuevo, pero es lo que tienes en la pregunta.
```P1.sort_values(by=['Chile', 'Brasil', 'Uruguay'], ascending=[True, False, True]) ``` en este caso de ejemplo, estamos ordenado chile de forma acendente, Brasil de forma descendente y Uruguay de forma ascendente.

Comment: hmmm, lo probare y te digo . ok. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aquí muestro los caminos que escogí para resolver las inquietudes anteriores:
Dado el siguiente diccionario:

```py
D = {'': ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos'],
     'Argentina': [3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 4],
     'Mexico': [3, 0, 3, 0, 6, 12, 0],
     'Colombia': [3, 3, 0, 0, 7, 1, 9],
     'Cuba': [3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4]}

print( df = pd.DataFrame(D)).T

                0  1  2  3   4   5       6
           JJ  G  P  E  GF  GC  Puntos
Argentina   3  1  1  1   5   6       4
Mexico      3  0  3  0   6  12       0
Colombia    3  3  0  0   7   1       9
Cuba        3  1  1  1   5   4       4
```

Para eliminar los 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 lo  que hice fue lo siguiente:

```py
print(( pd.DataFrame(D,  index = ['','','','','','',''])).T)

         JJ  G  P  E  GF  GC  Puntos
Argentina   3  1  1  1   5   6       4
Mexico      3  0  3  0   6  12       0
Colombia    3  3  0  0   7   1       9
Cuba        3  1  1  1   5   4       4
```

Pero como lo que yo quería además era organizar las columnas por los valores tuve que hacer lo siguiente:

```py
del D['']

print(D)

{'Argentina': [3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 4], 'Mexico': [3, 0, 3, 0, 6, 12, 0], 'Colombia': [3, 3, 0, 0, 7, 1, 9], 'Cuba': [3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4]}

D3 = pd.DataFrame(D,  index = ['JJ', 'G', 'P', 'E', 'GF', 'GC', 'Puntos']).sort_values(by=['Puntos','GC','GF'], ascending=False, axis = 1)
print((D3).T)

JJ  G  P  E  GF  GC  Puntos
Colombia    3  3  0  0   7   1       9
Argentina   3  1  1  1   5   6       4
Cuba        3  1  1  1   5   4       4
Mexico      3  0  3  0   6  12       0
```

Y listo
Índices redefinidos y columnas ordenadas, pero todas ascending.

**Queda pendiente *ordenarlas ascending Y descending* etc.!!!!!!!**

Saludos